# run jQuery when HTML is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var url='http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url=\'http://stackoverflow.com/\' and xpath=\'//div[@id="question-mini-list"]//h3//a                       \'&format=json&callback=?';

    $.getJSON( url, function(data){
        $.each(data.query.results.a, function(){       
            $('#stack').append('<div><a href="http://stackoverflow.com'+this.href +'">'+this.content+'</a></div>')          
        })
    })
});
```

HTML

```
<section id="stack">

</section>
```

The jQuery code is borrowed from an earlier post (Thanks!), but my question is: Shouldn't the jQuery code run when the page loads, the way it's displayed here? Im using coda 2. The jQuery is saved as .js-file, and the html is saved as .html. Both files are located in the same directory.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Works fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/G4jDz/

Comment: Let's see your script references.

Comment: @Zenith I know. But it didn't work in coda 2.

Comment: @Nilzone The problem was to do with your script placement (which you should have shown instead of making people guess) not coda 2

Comment: @Zenith You're right. I should have added the all my HTML-instead of parts.

Comment: @Nilzone- No worries, it wasn't meant to be critical, as long as you do it next time it's all cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you define a link to your javascript file in the `<head>` of your `index.html` page.

```html
<script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="path/to/javascript.js"></script>
```